# how define C structure: c-linkage and udt

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have dll written on language X with C-ABI interface.
And I want to use this C-ABI from my c++ program.

I wrote in main.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
struct Foo {
  const char * const data;
  unsigned len;
};
struct Foo f(void);
}

int main()
{
}
```

And got warning from compiler (visual c++/15.7.5/windows 7/32bit):

> (7): warning C4190: 'f' has C-linkage specified, but returns
>   UDT 'Foo' which is incompatible with C
>
> (7): note: see declaration of 'Foo'

Here godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/ztx1kf

I read [Error in C++ code linkage: warning C4190: type has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT which is incompatible with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901697/error-in-c-code-linkage-warning-c4190-type-has-c-linkage-specified-but-retu), but in my case I have no "c++ code"
at all in my POD struct.

How can I convince compiler that this is not **C++** `struct Foo`, but **C** `struct Foo`?

I try to move it to separate header file (.h), but this is change nothing.

If I replace `const char * const data` with `const char *` warning disappear,
what I also don't understand, but I don't want to change definition of struct.

Comment: [no repro](https://godbolt.org/g/Zr4RVC)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c

Comment: @JamesPoag I tried `typedef`, this is not helps

Comment: @VTT do you use the same version Visual Studio as I (Visual Studio 2017/15.7.5)?

Comment: VS version is printed at the bottom of assembly listing window.

Comment: @VTT I don't think this is relevant source, even with `/W4` it don't print relevant warning, while default visual studio installation on my machine print warning about `C-linkage` `UDT` with all default settings and empty console project.

Comment: Interestingly your godbolt example works fine with recent clang and gcc, even with `-Wall -Wpedantic`.

Comment: I answered it in this new question: [Tales from the MSVC extern "C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431947/tales-from-the-msvc-extern-c), so voting as duplicate.

Comment: Added a tweaked answer here explaining the specific case presented here, but the answer is largely the same.

Answer (score 1):

The [x64 calling convention docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019) explain that UDTs are returned in `eax` if they are small enough and fit some criteria:

> To return a user-defined type by value in RAX, it must have a length of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. It must also have no user-defined constructor, destructor, or copy assignment operator; no private or protected non-static data members; no non-static data members of reference type; no base classes; no virtual functions; and no data members that do not also meet these requirements.

While `Foo` is a *StandardLayout* type (and as such we would expect it to work), the `const` non-static data member makes the copy assignment operator deleted, which is probably what they mean, even if it says "user-defined". This makes it, by the way, a non *TrivialType* and therefore not a POD in the C++03 sense.

It also exceeds the maximum size, but even if we removed `len`, the above would still prevent it to be a "POD".

Similarly, the [x86 calling convention docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019) explain something similar:

> [...] except for 8-byte structures, which are returned in the EDX:EAX register pair. Larger structures are returned in the EAX register as pointers to hidden return structures. [...] Structures that are not PODs will not be returned in registers.

For instance, a function like the following:

```
struct Foo
{ 
    const uint32_t x;
};

Foo f(void)
{
    Foo foo = { 12345 };
    return foo;
}
```

When compiled under x86/x64 C++ mode, `Foo` is considered a non-POD and therefore `eax`/`rax` contains the address of the object as the docs lead us to expect.

However, when compiler under x86/x64 C mode, `Foo` is considered a POD (we are compiling C) and therefore you will get the `uint32_t` value directly in `eax`.

Therefore, calling `f` from C won't work, even if we set the language linkage to C, which is why the warning appears.

Answer (score 0):

[C, of course, can have const struct member](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FmbTV7L4LOq1NEGH)s

Some kind of a solution (as of today): Simply disable the warning 4190, if using MSVC.