# Returning a struct from PInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

Im trying to return a struct from a call to a c++ dll from c#, and I get some complicated and bad behaviour that I dont understand. If my struct contains a constructor I get a memory access violation when returning it, if it is less than 12 bytes. If it is larger there is no problem. If I remove the constructor it works for all sizes. I suppose this could have something to do with my calls being c-style but I cannot find information about this. So it would be much appreciated if someone could explain or point my in a good direction of what is going on. Below are examples of code that does and does not work:

**Code that works**

C++ side header:

```
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

struct Struct4Byte
{
 int x1;
};

struct Struct12Byte
{
 int x1;
 int x2;
 int x3;
 Struct12Byte() { x1 = 0; x2 = 1; x3 = 2; }
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 DLL_API Struct4Byte Function4Byte(int x);
 DLL_API Struct12Byte Function12Byte(int x);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

C++ file:

```
Struct4Byte Function4Byte(int x)
{
 Struct4Byte output;
 output.x1 = 1 + x;
 return output;
}

Struct12Byte Function12Byte(int x)
{
 Struct12Byte output;
 output.x1 = 1 + x;
 output.x2 = 2 + x;
 output.x3 = 3 + x;
 return output;
}
```

On the calling side (C#) I do:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Struct4Byte
{
 public int x1;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct Struct12Byte
{
 public int x1;
 public int x2;
 public int x3;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Struct4Byte result1 = Function4Byte(3);
            Struct12Byte result2 = Function12Byte(3);
    }

    [DllImport(@"PInvokeCheck.dll")]
    internal static extern Struct4Byte Function4Byte(int x);

    [DllImport(@"PInvokeCheck.dll")]
    internal static extern Struct12Byte Function12Byte(int x);
}
```

**Code that does not work**

If I now change in the header file the definition of the Struct4Byte to:

```
struct Struct4Byte
{
 int x1;
 Struct4Byte(){ x1 = 0; }
};
```

then I get Memory Access violation.

I've noted something that might be of interest. The problem is already when calling Function4Byte. Putting a brakpoint and viewing x in the function (I put the function again below) shows that x get some random value.

```
Struct4Byte Function4Byte(int x)
{
 Struct4Byte output;
 output.x1 = 1 + x;
 return output;
}
```

Comment: `CallingConvention` should be `Cdecl` maybe? And what about padding, x64 will pad to 8 bytes

Comment: That did not seem to have any effect. But Im not 100% sure how to do that padding. I used `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]` in c# and I also tried the `#pragma pack(8)` in c++. But no improvement.

Comment: Oddly I have the same problem with a structure having two int members (so 8 bytes) but not for 12 bytes or larger.  

I think I can get around the problem simply by not including any constructor or adding some extra data. But, then I don't really know if the problem is solved or if it just happens to work by accident.

Comment: What about not returning a struct, but passing a reference to a struct as parameter? [Marshaling Classes, Structures, and Unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions)

Comment: That is clearly an option and what Ive done for most of the data I return. But my main concern is not to get it working but understanding why it does not. Otherwise, chances are high that this might also be a problem when I return my structure in some other way.

Answer (score -1):

I might have found the issue. Their was a warning that I had missed that: warning C4190: 'Function4Byte' has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT 'Struct4Byte' which is incompatible with C. From this discussion it is clear that it can lead to some undefined behaviour and that the layout of the struct may change: [Error in C++ code linkage: warning C4190: type has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT which is incompatible with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901697/error-in-c-code-linkage-warning-c4190-type-has-c-linkage-specified-but-retu)

So that seems explain the problem I've had.

Answer (score -1):

Yea returning structs like that isn't supported and the none of Microsoft's mainline P/Invoke articles represent an example of returning structs like that. None that I read anyways.

Here's a git hub example of your project doing it the correct way.

https://github.com/ditchcode/PInvokeTesting

I found this article most helpful on the marshaling of Structs and Classes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/passing-structures

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason is explained in the calling conventions.

[x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170)

> User-defined types can be returned by value from global functions and static member functions. To return a user-defined type by value in RAX, it must have a length of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. It must also have no user-defined constructor, destructor, or copy assignment operator. It can have no private or protected non-static data members, and no non-static data members of reference type. It can't have base classes or virtual functions. And, it can only have data members that also meet these requirements. (This definition is essentially the same as a C++03 POD type. Because the definition has changed in the C++11 standard, we don't recommend using std::is_pod for this test.) Otherwise, the caller must allocate memory for the return value and pass a pointer to it as the first argument. The remaining arguments are then shifted one argument to the right. The same pointer must be returned by the callee in RAX.

[x86 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)

> On x86 platforms, all arguments are widened to 32 bits when they are passed. Return values are also widened to 32 bits and returned in the EAX register, except for 8-byte structures, which are returned in the EDX:EAX register pair. Larger structures are returned in the EAX register as pointers to hidden return structures. Parameters are pushed onto the stack from right to left. Structures that are not PODs will not be returned in registers.

Doing what is says for x64 is a good alternative solution.

> the caller must allocate memory for the return value and pass a pointer to it as the first argument

So your code would look like this

```
Struct4Byte Function4Byte(Struct4Byte& output, int x)
{
 output.x1 = 1 + x;
}

Struct12Byte Function12Byte(Struct12Byte& output, int x)
{
 output.x1 = 1 + x;
 output.x2 = 2 + x;
 output.x3 = 3 + x;
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Struct4Byte = Function4Byte(out var result1, 3);
        Function12Byte(out var result2, 3);
    }

    [DllImport(@"PInvokeCheck.dll")]
    internal static extern void Function4Byte(out Struct4Byte result, int x);

    [DllImport(@"PInvokeCheck.dll")]
    internal static extern void Function12Byte(out Struct12Byte result, intx);
}
```